# Scene flow equivalent to 3D Optical Flow?

Tags: image-processing, 3d

I'm trying to understand what is optical flow and how is working. And i saw that optical flow can be computed for 2D images and also for images which have depth information(3D). And there are 2 terms which i don't know if are equivalent. So the question is scene flow is equivalent to 3D Optical Flow ? Can anyone point me to some resource which explain this kind of informations for a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. Those two terms are equivalent.

> 3D optical flow on a moving surface (such as a growing leaf) is called
>   range flow and also produces 3D velocity (U, V, W) on all surface
>   points of some scanned object that is moving over time. Now the 3D
>   constraint equation uses x and y derivatives of Z, the depth value
>   (either scanned or computed) at each surface point. Range flow is
>   also often called scene flow.

The source of the answer and detail explanation can be found here: http://computerrobotvision.org/2009/tutorial_day/CRV2009diffopticalflow.pdf